# Assembly instruction in STVD IDE for STM8 microcontroller

Tags: c, assembly, stm8

I'm programming `STM8` micro controller in `STVD`. I happen to use an assembly instruction in the middle of code. As shown  [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html#Basic-Asm)
I used a instruction as below

```
 asm("MOV $00500A,#$3");
```

But I'm facing with following error

```
 #error cpstm8 ..\app\sched.c:183(5) missing prototype
```

Can anyone help me in fixing this?

Comment: Is [tag:gcc] your compiler? Isn't [Cosmic](http://www.cosmic-software.com/stm8.php) your current compiler? If so, use its manual...

Comment: I'm using cosmic compiler. In it's manual I couldn't find

Comment: Well, looking at the [tag:gcc] one is not the solution... ;) Look at [this link](http://cosmic-software.com/manuals.php)....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For STM8 assembly instruction, you need to use `_` before the instruction as shown below

```
 _asm("MOV $00500A,#$3");
```